# Why does echo !() print the contents of the current directory?

Tags: bash

I have been teaching myself the meaning of various bash 'reserved words'.

In doing this, I inadvertently typed the command

```
echo !()
```

To my surprise, this command executes, and produces output identical to the command

```
echo *
```

In other words, the output was a list of the contents of the current directory

```
file1 file2 directory1 directory2
```

Why is bash essentially expanding `!()` to `*` ?

I can't determine the meaning of `()`, as it seems to be an invalid expression in other contexts.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's bash's [extglob pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) syntax which it copied from the Korn shell (a subset thereof). `!(pattern)`, when the `extglob` has been enabled one way or another (like via the `bash_completion` add-on in interactive shells) expands to the names of the (non-hidden by default) files in the current working directory that don't match `pattern`.

With an empty pattern, that's all files in the current directory whose name is *not* the empty string, but a file name cannot be empty anyway so that's all the (non-hidden by default) files.

You'll get the same in `zsh` with `echo ^` when its `extendedglob` option is enabled where `^pattern` is its equivalent of ksh's `!(pattern)`.

Comment: Somewhat more usefully, e.g. `foo!(*~)` would give all files that start with `foo`, but  do not end with a `~`. Though one might try to use `foo*!(~)`, which doesn't work since the `*` matches the `~`, and the last `!(~)` only sees an empty string at the end, which it doesn't reject.